# Create radio button list from object elements

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I would like to take one of the objects and create a list of radio buttons from the objects contents. Here is my code so far.

```
var allQuestions = [{question: "This is question number one", choices: ["one", "two", "three", "four"], correctAnswer:"two"},{question: "This is question number two", choices: ["dog", "cat", "bear", "lion"], correctAnswer:"bear"}];

var currentQuestion = allQuestions[1].question;

document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = currentQuestion;

function choiceList() { 

    for (choices in allQuestions[0]) {

    var choiceSelection = document.createElement('input');

    choiceSelection.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    choiceSelection.setAttribute('name', 'choice');

    document.getElementById('answersBox').innerHTML = choiceSelection;
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <label id="question">Question:</label><br />
        <div id="answersBox">
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="save" />
    </form>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

The problem is, the radio buttons are not showing up in the answersBox div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially you need to append each element you create to the proper node in the DOM, rather than set its HTML value (which wouldn't work, since choiceSelection is a DOM element and not a string representing its HTML code)

In short- change

`document.getElementById('answersBox').innerHTML = choiceSelection;`

to

`document.getElementById('answersBox').appendChild(choiceSelection);`

I've implemented adding the `label` HTML element next to the radio button.

Here's a working [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/vuPB4/)

I would also like for you to notice that `for (choices in allQuestions[0])` creates an internal variable in the for loop called "choices" that iterates over the properties of allQuestions[0], in this case they are "question", "choices" and "correctAnswer".

I think what you intended to do is to iterate over the array of "choices", which can be done like so:
`for (choice in question.choices)` - then with each step of the for loop, choice is populated with the array index.

You can then access the choice text from inside the loop like so:
`question.choices[choice]`

Answer (score 2):

Append your radio buttons to a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DocumentFragment) within your `for` loop. After the loop append the fragment (containing all of your options) to the `document` itself.

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (choices in allQuestions[0]) {

    var choiceSelection = document.createElement('input');
    choiceSelection.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    choiceSelection.setAttribute('name', 'choice');

    frag.appendChild(choiceSelection);
}

document.getElementById('answersBox').appendChild(frag);
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/vFkpY/)

- There's a good article [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) about using document fragments.
- [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild)
- [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DocumentFragment)

**EDIT:**

[**Updated with labels**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/vFkpY/3/)

Comment: Thanks Chase. Is there a way to take the "choice" value e.g. "one", "two", "three" and place it after the radio button?

Comment: What do you mean by `after` the radio button?

Comment: Well, the first radio button would have "one" after it, the second would have "two" etc. etc. In HTML it would like like <input type="radio" name="choice">one

Comment: @user2137425 - That's what I thought you meant, but I wasn't quite sure. I've updated the response with labels, but it seems you've decided on another answer. This is fine, but I do suggest you look into writing all your changes into a document fragment before appending them directly into the document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **.appendChild** function because **choiceSelection** is a DOM Element in your code and not a HTML string.

`document.getElementById('answersBox').appendChild(choiceSelection);`

Also I don't see you calling **choiceList()**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CUAMp/)

Comment: @user2137425 I've updated my answer above to reflect how to add labels. Take a look

Comment: @user2137425 Next time say also that you want to display text for each radio button.

Comment: @letiagoalves I think this comment was intended for the OP?

Comment: @OpherV yes it was. Sorry. Updated.